# Check if an individual is an instance of a class using OWL in Java

Tags: java, semantic-web, owl

How do you check if an individual is an instance of a class java OWL? I was thinking about getting all the instances of a class and checking if that instance belongs to that set.

Comment: Hello, this seems to be your first question here. You should consider adding the code where you want to test if your object belongs to a particular class.

You may also want to have a look at the `object.getClass()` function as a primer.

Comment: This is about using Web Ontology Language (OWL) API in Java.

Comment: For a proper answer you would need a reasoner. then you can call `reasoner.getTypes(ind, false)` for an individual `ind` and check if the class `cls` is contained in the set. See http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/reasoner/OWLReasoner.html#getTypes-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLNamedIndividual-boolean-

Comment: Or you create the class assertion axiom `ax`, and ask the reasoner whether this axiom is entailed by `reasoner.isEntailed(ax);`, see http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/reasoner/OWLReasoner.html#isEntailed-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAxiom-

Comment: Or like you said, get all instances of the class `cls` with `reasoner.getInstances(cls, false)`, see http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_4/org/semanticweb/owlapi/reasoner/OWLReasoner.html#getInstances-org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLClassExpression-boolean-.

Comment: How do you check if a class cls is contained in the set?